# Show that $\mathcal{I}(V)$ is the product ideal of $k=\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, affine-geometry

This question is from Dummit and Foote Chapter 15 (Exercise 15). I want to show the following:

If $k=\mathbb{F}_2$ and $V=\{0,0),(1,1)\}\subset\mathbb{A}^2$, show that $\mathcal{I}(V)$ is the product ideal $m_1m_2$ where $m_1=(x,y)$ and $m_2=(x-1,y-1)$.

I think that I am overthinking this.. it feels sort of intuitive perhaps, but I am new to affine algebraic sets, so I am unsure of how to prove this.

Comment: My book also provides me with a general definition: for any subset $A$ of $\mathbb{A}^n$, define $\mathcal{I}(A)=\{f\in k[x_1,...,x_n|f(a_1,...,a_n)=0$ for all $(a_1,...,a_n)\in A\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V_{0}= (0,0)$ and $V_{1}= (1,1)$. Then $V = V_{0} \cup V_{1}  $. Hence $I(V)= I(V_{0})\cap I(V_{1})$.  Now can you  see that $I(V_{0}) = (x,y)$ and $I(V_{1}) = (x-1, y-1)$, using the definition you gave in comment? And since the ideals $(x-1, y-1), (x,y)$ are coprime, $I(V_{0})\cap I(V_{1})=I(V_{0})I(V_{1})$.

Comment: How do we know $\mathcal{I}(V)=\mathcal{I}(V_0)\cdot\mathcal{I}(V_1)$? In my book, I have a property that states for two subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{A}^n$, $\mathcal{I}(A\cup B)=\mathcal{I}(A)\cap\mathcal{I}(B)$

Comment: So wouldn't that mean $\mathcal{I}(V)=\mathcal{I}(V_0)\cap\mathcal{I}(V_1)$?

Comment: In general it's the intersection , but here since ideals are relatively prime  it doesn't matter.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense but i don't see why the ideals are necessarily relatively prime- where is this property derived from?

Comment: Ideals  $I$ and $J$ , in a ring $R$  with unity are coprime if $I + J =R$. In your case one quick way of seeing that ideals are copime is that both of them are maximal ideals .